# AlarmManager. Запустить приложение при срабатывании будильника

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

```
public class HelperAlarm  extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final public static String ONE_TIME="onetime";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm=(PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl= pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"YOUR TAG");
//Осуществляем блокировку
        wl.acquire();

//Здесь можно делать обработку.
        Bundle extras= intent.getExtras();
        StringBuilder msgStr=new StringBuilder();

        if(extras!=null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
//проверяем параметр ONE_TIME, если это одиночный будильник,
//выводим соответствующее сообщение.
            msgStr.append("Одноразовый будильник: ");
        }
        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

        Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//Разблокируем поток.
        wl.release();
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent=new Intent(context,  HelperAlarm.class);
        intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);//Задаем параметр интента
        PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intent,0);
//Устанавливаем интервал срабатывания в 5 секунд.
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),1000,pi);
    }

    public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent  = new Intent(context, HelperAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);//Отменяем будильник, связанный с интентом данного класса
    }

    public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context){
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent=new Intent(context, HelperAlarm.class);
        intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);//Задаем параметр интента
        PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intent,0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
    }
}
```

Как мне запустить приложение при срабатывании будильника, даже, если экран выключен?

Comment: Как вариант можно написать сервис в котрором в  будут регистрироваться ресиверы и в методе `onReceve` делать `startActivity`

Comment: Я пробовал, вызывает ошибку. Мне не понятно, какие параметры передавать в intent.